# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected

Tags: php, parsing, syntax-error

I get this error when i'm trying to install cometchat on my site

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home3/user/public_html/mysite/cometchat/integration.php on line 18

this is the code from line 18 to 21

```
if (!file_exists((dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'includes'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config.php')) {
    echo "Please check if cometchat is installed in the correct directory.<br /> The 'cometchat' folder should be placed at <VLDPERSONALS_HOME_DIRECTORY>/cometchat";
    exit;
}
```

can someone please tell me what is wrong and share the right code fix

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a parentheses.

```
if ( !file_exists( (dirname(dirname(FILE)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'includes'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config.php') ) ) {
    echo "Please check if cometchat is installed in the correct directory. The 'cometchat' folder should be placed at /cometchat"; exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing bracket. Try

```
if (!file_exists((dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'includes'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config.php'))) { // note there are three brackets at the end of the line
    echo "Please check if cometchat is installed in the correct directory.<br /> The 'cometchat' folder should be placed at <VLDPERSONALS_HOME_DIRECTORY>/cometchat";
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems quite simple. You have extra parentheses in your code :
I have modified the code.

if(!file_exists(dirname(dirname(**FILE**)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'includes'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config.php')) 
    {
    echo "Please check if cometchat is installed in the correct directory.
 The 'cometchat' folder should be placed at /cometchat";
    exit;
}

Comment: Not only is the question several months old, but your answer provides nothing new and besides we should not be answering typo questions - StackOverflow is intended to provide useful information to present *and future* developers. Nobody is going to be helped by this person forgetting a parenthesis...